# Cant get data from express server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, http, get

I am trying to send a `GET` request and receive a response on my client side (react).

On my express server:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send('Hey, I came from the express server');
})
```

When I use postman to sent the request I receive a good answer:

[image]

So I don't think the problem is with the server.

### A problem:

When I try to send the request using react like this:

```
  const getData = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8081", {
      method: "GET",
      mode: 'no-cors'
    }).then(response => console.log(response));
  }
```

For some reason the response status is 0 and not 200 (I am receiving status code of `200` when checking this request with postman and also on the chrome network tab).
In addition, if I try to print `response.body` it will be null.

**The response:**

```
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: "opaque"
url: ""
[[Prototype]]: Response
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you using Create React App?

Comment: @Andy Yes, this is how I have created my client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can add a proxy property](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) to your `package.json`:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8081",
```

And then just use `/` as your fetch endpoint.

```
fetch('/'...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to transfer your response to an text or json like:

```
  const getData = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8081", {
      method: "GET",
      mode: 'no-cors'
    }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data))
  }
```

Besides `.json()` there are even more methods. Its everything written down in the docs. You just need to google it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#methods